# How do I get the value of specific cells in a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cant Figure Out What's Wrong New To Asp.net

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptConcept" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="about_us_section">
                            <div class="aboutus">
                                <%--<h2>Concepts</h2>--%>
                                <h2>Collection</h2>
                                <%#Eval("description")%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Thats .Cs file
  How To get the second table Row 2 Column 5 value in Repeater

```
if (ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rptConcept.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
                rptConcept.DataBind();
                //var datasource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(5);
                //rptConcept.DataSource = datasource; 
                //rptConcept.DataBind();
            }

But I want table[2].Rows[0];
description column Which Index is 5
```

Please Help.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want, where is that code you pasted? In RowDataBound? In Page_Load? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: on page load- i want to get table[2].row[0] column 5 which column name is description value in repaeter which id-rptConcept

Comment: Then why don't you just do ds.Tables[2].Row[0]["description"] to get the value

Comment: & what about the aspx ?? it throws an Error :'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'description'.

Comment: You only want to show that specific description and not anything else? Then why do you have a repeater? Just show it in Label or Literal.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion